# Mersenne twister middle word

Tags: terminology, cryptography, pseudo-random-generators

In some literature, as well as in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), the middle term parameter *m* of Mersenne twister is called "number of parallel sequences". Why? What is meant here by "parallel sequences"?